# Popup before window is closed

Tags: jquery, popup, popupwindow

I want to open a custom popup box when browser close button is pressed, I want to ask a question to the users exiting that why are they leaving my site. I have checked quite few posts but the best thing I found is something like this post

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847156/jquery-dialog-box-before-closing-browser-window`

But this just opens a browser default confirm box. I want to open a custom box like colorbox. My page is `http://cwstudio.in/browserclose/`

right now I am using `alert` function to open the popup but if I donot use the alert, the browser donot waits for my popup and just close it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Its unlikely this will work, as most browsers now have inbuilt features to stop popups, or prevent the default close action being halted when the window is closed.

Comment: so there is no way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascipt `window.onunload` or jquery `unload` method:

**Javascript**:

```
 window.onunload = function(){
 //Do something
 }
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(window).unload(function(){
 //Do something
 });
```

**Update:** If the user has blocked pop-ups then you can not do anything. *However* you can use a `confirm` box instead of showing popup:

```
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
```

Comment: I am using `$(document).ready(function(e) {`
    `$("#button").colorbox();`
`});`

Comment: and then `$(window).unload(function(){`
`$("#button").click();`
` });`

Comment: so this is suppose to open the popup in colorbox but it doesnot wait for it until I use `alert`

Comment: If browser have settings to block the pop ups.the ball is not in ur court then

Comment: I need to show 8 options, is it possible in confirm box in anyway?

Comment: the popup blocker should block `window.open` or it will block the colorbox popup too?

Comment: try using return false at the end of above functions.i am not sure but it should work.

Comment: so its not possible. You can give confirm box.and if user clicks ok then try showing a div with return falls after it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     return 'Any string';
};
```