# Confirmation Before Closing a Popup Window?

Tags: php, jquery

I have developed the code for a popup window after clicking on a link. But what I want is to show a confirmation alert before closing the popup window.

How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
window.onload=test_create();
function test_create()
{
    alert('Test Function');
}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(body).unload(function()
{
   alert('Close');
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    alert('Close');
});
```

or if you want to make a question if the user want really to close the page you can try this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to close this window")){
         return true;
    }else{
         return false;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
   return confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these way

Javascript:

```
window.onunload = function(){
 //Do something
 }
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
 //Do something
 });
```

Comment: copy and pasted from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735076/popup-before-window-is-closed

Comment: @Neel this is not copy paste ok all dev s know these codes

Comment: +1 this solution works fine, isn't necessary to downvote it @Downvoters

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create popups on `JavaScript` in my opinion is based on create div elements
dinamically for have you'r on popups withs you'r own values and styles.
Anyway I think you are looking for somting like `JavaScript prompt()`, take a look to [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp). There you have an [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZDYa/) exemple.