# Create alert message on closing popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created some code to open a YouTube video in pop-up for a few seconds. Everything is working well with this code. All I need is to show an alert to user if he/she is going to close the pop-up window. Now the problem is that the pop-up window is not related to parent window, so how can I close it?

Here is the code I am using:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var myWindow;
    $("#idview").click(function() {
        var vidurl = 'www.youtube.com';
        counter();
        myWindow = window.open(vidurl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");

    });

    function counter() {
        var n = $('.c').attr('id');
        var c = n;
        $('.c').text(c);
        setInterval(function() {
            c++;
            if (c <= 41) {
                $('.c').text(c);
            }
            if (c == 41) {
                $('.c').text(n);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }



    setInterval(function() {
        myWindow.close();
    }, 45000);

    window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;

    function closingCode() {
        alert('hitme');
        return null;
    }


});
```

I just want to fire a function before closing the popup window.

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735076/popup-before-window-is-closed) It helps you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fire a function before closing popup window. just call it right before closing the window.

```
setInterval(function() {
  your_callback_function();
  myWindow.close();
}, 45000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(function() {
    if (condition) {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

**or:**

```
if (condition){    
   $('dialog id').dialog('close');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
  myWindow = window.open(vidurl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");    
  myWindow.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
```

Comment: but the problem is this is not working because the parent window and the popup window is different. like if my window is www.abcd.com. and popup url is youtube.com